# Using jq in malformed json file

Tags: jq

Hello is it possible to use jq to extract field in a malformed json file

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('58049da30b78a4a11e3c9869'),
    'name': 'joe bam',
    'username': 'joe_bam',
    'contact_info': {
        'email': 'N/a@mail.com'
    },
    'color': 'Blue',
    'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 18, 11, 16, 19, 737000),
    'created_at': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 17, 9, 45, 7, 226000),
    'token': '$2y$10$VMgv1S/NiGzkPsGhc4S.6eGFvEXv5YenlWQNdqUbVy4aGaeKOyxpi',
    'views': 29,
    'status_logged': True,
    'provider': 'signup'
}
```

In this example i want to extract `jq -r '[.name, .username, |contact_info .email] | @csv'`

Is that possible ?? cause i have validate this json and give me errors

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing malformed here. This is an object out of mongodb (or similar) and it is a valid object. If you want to convert it to JSON, modify the query you use to get it (there is a simple method like 'tojson' or similar for this) or write a couple of lines in pure javascript to do it.

Comment: @thanasisp interessting checking that....
But what is tojson ? first time i hear about.

Answer (score 0):

As user  thanasisp says [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618338/using-jq-in-malformed-json-file#comment1156569_618338), this document is likely the output of a MongoDB query and the issue would be better solved by properly converting it to JSON using the database engine.

However, the `yq` utility from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ (a YAML parser wrapped around `jq`) is able to (kinda) parse the document as it is, as if it was YAML.

```
$ yq -r '[.name, .username, .contact_info.email] | @csv' file
"joe bam","joe_bam","N/a@mail.com"
```

I say "kinda", because this mess is what you get if you pass it through the identity filter:

```
$ yq . file
{
  "_id": "ObjectId('58049da30b78a4a11e3c9869')",
  "name": "joe bam",
  "username": "joe_bam",
  "contact_info": {
    "email": "N/a@mail.com"
  },
  "color": "Blue",
  "updated_at": "datetime.datetime(2017",
  "5": null,
  "18": null,
  "11": null,
  "16": null,
  "19": null,
  "737000)": null,
  "created_at": "datetime.datetime(2016",
  "10": null,
  "17": null,
  "9": null,
  "45": null,
  "7": null,
  "226000)": null,
  "token": "$2y$10$VMgv1S/NiGzkPsGhc4S.6eGFvEXv5YenlWQNdqUbVy4aGaeKOyxpi",
  "views": 29,
  "status_logged": true,
  "provider": "signup"
}
```